# Compiler optimization of public static final and OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, compiler-optimization

I have an OSGi bundle b1 exporting a class with

```
public static final String MYVAL = "a"; //version 1
```

and a second bundle b2 is compiled and deployed using version 1 of b1.

Later on I change the value in b1 to

```
public static final String MYVAL = "b"; //version 2
```

but I only recompile and deploy b1, b2 is unchanged and not recompiled.

Is it possible that the b2 still sees value `a` at runtime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of a referenced static final primitive or string is directly inlined into the using class. So unrelated to OSGI and any visibility rules, `b2` will still contain an embedded `MYVAL` value of "a".

I think this is documented in the [Java Language Specification, Section 13.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9):

> If a field is a constant variable (§4.12.4), then deleting the keyword final or changing its value will not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries by causing them not to run, but **they will not see any new value for the usage of the field unless they are recompiled**. This is true even if the usage itself is not a compile-time constant expression (§15.28).

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524336/139595) shows a workaround. Changing the declaration so it is no longer a constant expression disables this inlining behaviour.

```
public static final String MYVAL = String.valueOf("a");
```

Comment: You should be able to avoid the new String object and use the interned "a" with:

`public static final String MYVAL;
{
  MYVAL = "a";
}`

Comment: @BJHargrave: `valueOf` delegates to `toString` which will in fact return the same interned instance. I used `valueOf` to be consistent when creating a numeric constant as in `Integer.valueOf(1)`.

Comment: True, but valueOf is a method which must be executed while ```= "a"``` is an assignment to a string in the constant pool.