# Mac: Full Screen JFrame losing keybindings from mouseadapter

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe, fullscreen

On my Mac, fullscreen JFrames initially have key bindings that do not work, and the computer outputs alert beeps each time I try to type. There is a workaround, though, after fully initializing my JFrame, I added these lines of code and all the errors stopped:

```
   setVisible(false);
   setVisible(true);
```

Here's the source of this workaround: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2012-November/005109.html

Another problem which is yet to be solved is adding a mouse adapter to my full screen JFrame application. Whenever I clicked, the focus changed--to where, I couldn't quite tell, but setting the inputmap of my keybindings to each one of the three options didn't help.

I even tried redoing the workaround when the mouse was clicked by adding this:
            event.getComponent().setVisible(false);
            event.getComponent().setVisible(true);
but to no avail.

**Here is an SSCCE of the problem (it will only show up on a mac):**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FocusTest extends JFrame{
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

    public FocusTest() {
       MyPanelDescendent myPanelDescendent = new MyPanelDescendent();
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       getContentPane().add(myPanelDescendent);
       pack();
       setLocationByPlatform(true);
       setVisible(true);

       KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
       Action escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             dispose();
             System.exit(0);
            }
       };
       getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(escapeKeyStroke, "ESCAPE");
       getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", escapeAction);

       GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
       GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
       gs.setFullScreenWindow(this);

       setVisible(false);
       setVisible(true);
    }
    private class MyPanelAscendent extends JPanel{
        public MyPanelAscendent() {
           setFocusable(true);
           requestFocusInWindow();

             getInputMap(0).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"), "pressed");
             getActionMap().put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
                   @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                       if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                           System.out.println("a was pressed");
                       }
                   }
             });

           addMouseListener(new MyAdapter());
        }
    }
    private class MyPanelDescendent extends MyPanelAscendent {
        public MyPanelDescendent() {
            super();
        }
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            event.getComponent().setVisible(false);
            event.getComponent().setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             new FocusTest();
          }
       });
    }
}
```

If you press the a key, then click, then do it again, it will not work. The same goes for the escape key: if you click then try to use it, it won't work.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/2770572) is an example for fullscreen posted by trashgod which I've also found impossible to make work with both keybindings, fullscreen, and a mouse adapter at the same time.

Comment: `the computer outputs alert beeps each time I try to type` I don't use a Mac but I noticed the requestFocusInWindow() method in your constructor. This does nothing because you can only request focus on a component that is displayed on a visible GUI. So maybe try invoking that method after you set the frame to full screen (instead of the setInvisible/Visible). Sounds to me likes its beeping because no component has focus.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my question because it wasn't clear enough that I had already solved that with the work around. This is a recreation of a small part in a larger application I have definitely has the panel on a visible GUI. Now, after I click with the mouse, there is no beeping when I type, which tells me something must have focus? However, there is no response from the key bindings.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? I'm totally lost on this still, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried adding the mouse adapter directly to the JFrame instead of the JPanel?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't edited this application for a while, but I'll reply here with an answer to that if I ever try it.