# Make Java compiler include symbolic constant field reference in class file - possible?

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist, bcel, javap

It is well known that the Java compiler pulls in constant field values from other classes **at compile time**. The resulting class file does **not** contain a Constant Pool entry (of any type) for such constants.

Q: can the compiler be told to do just that? (Oracle JDK 7 would be nice)

As illustration, consider a piece of code
`out.println(some.other.class.FOO)` that reads FOO (say, `public static final int FOO = 1234`) and outputs it. I am able to find the references to `println` no problem, but the the constant is turned into an anonymous `sipush 1234`.

For class-level dependency analysis, it would be great to have transparency here! Note I'm not asking to make any changed value there *appear somehow* in the dependent code (see loads of other SO questions on that) ...

I'm thinking about a Java Compiler API plug-in to javac, but that sounds like a bit far-fetched? Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524150/is-it-possible-to-disable-javacs-inlining-of-static-final-variables?rq=1

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want the compiler to be told ? .. I think I may have an interesting answer...

Comment: Thanks @ RC for the other pointer. Sorry I had missed this one when searching (and probably some more...). @Jean-François, the idea is to create a synthetic (unused) Fieldref (like for GETSTATIC opcodes) into the Constant Pool, somehow. I realize that this would be for *own* code only (compilation required), but would keep the dep checker tool at least on class-level, not on source code level.

Comment: This would be doable in C, where `.obj` files (Java `.class`) are _linked_ to an executable (Java .jar), no longer using `.obj` files in the end product. In Java the .class is already submitted to a final optimization process. It would make more sense in java working with source code parsing, with AST (abstract syntax trees), see ASM and others.

Comment: @JoopEggen, [ASM](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm) works on byte code level as well, so there's no access to the AST. To bridge the gap to the source code, I am thinking about a "processor" plug-in to javac. This should have access to the AST, and can influence the byte code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [`final` variables initialized to constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4-300) can be so inlined. So if you want to avoid compile time inlining like that, the obvious approach is to either make the field non-`final` or make the initializing expression complicated enough that it is no longer considered constant (e.g. `(null == null) ? 1234 : 0)`) [¹](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Once you've already run the compiler it's too late, because the generated code is exactly equivalent to if you had inserted the constant inline instead of referencing a field.

If you are doing static analysis on the source code, you can obviously just use any of the standard dependency finding tools.

Comment: Not entirely true. If you have a non-static final boolean with a preassigned value that is used within a conditional expression within the same class, that value is also inlined in order to remove the conditional. For the sake of completness.

Comment: @Rafael Winterhalter: the use site doesn’t need to be in the same class, regardless of whether the field is `static` or not. Of course, it has to be in the case of `private` fields, but that’s also independent of the `static` flag. And, by the way, *every* `final` variable can be a compile-time constant, even local variables. (yes, that implies that if you declare a local variable like `final int foo=10;` you can use it’s name in a follow-up `switch` statement as a `case` label). Seems to be a common misconception to think that it was limited to `static` fields (or fields in general).

Comment: @Holger you are right, compile-time constants have nothing to do with fields in the first place, as it is implicit from the spec: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). I tried to add something to the answer. Mainly, I forgot about inner classes as I just assumed that non-static fields from other classes would not make a difference here as they cannot be referred to without going through an instance of that class which are again never compile-time constants. But you are right, of course.

Comment: @Rafael Winterhalter: you have to access an instance field via an instance, even if it’s a compile-time constant, to fulfill the formal rules but the value will get inlined or, more precise, the generated bytecode will contain a `null`-check to emulate the instance access (`javac` uses an `instance.getClass()`) followed by using the inlined constant value. Anyway, there is little use for instance fields that are actually compile-time constants as they are wasting per-instance storage for something that is never accessed (unless Reflection is involved).

Comment: @Holger I did not know that, thanks for the additional information. But do you have an example? I just tried to reproduce what you described but I cannot observe the `getClass`-driven `null`-check for `Foo$Bar`: `class Foo { final String foo = "foo"; class Bar { void bar() { System.out.println(foo); } } }` The value is just inlined without checking for the outer instance to not be `null`.

Comment: @Rafael Winterhalter: you are accessing the field via `this`; there is no need to check `this` against `null`. (this includes `Outer.this`) I was talking about accessing the field from another class, not being an inner class, where it is implied that the reference will be an ordinary variable rather than `this`…

Comment: @Holger That I really did not know. Thanks for the clarification! (For future reader's reference: `class Foo { final boolean foo = true; } class Bar { void bar(Foo foo) { boolean bar =  foo.foo } }`) This is especially interesting as the current C2 compiler throws a cached, stack-less `NullPointerException`: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073432 This javac compilation decision opens the doors for some happy debugging sessions.

Comment: @Holger: Interesting, I never knew that. Thanks for fixing things.