# Parse first element of JSON list with GSON

Tags: java, gson

In my project I'm using GSON to serialize and deserialize objects. Often I get a list of objects as JSON from a server but I'm only interested in the first element of the list. Is it possible with `@SerializedName` to only fetch the first element of the list?

I think about something like this: `@SerializedName("List[0]")`

Or what would you recommend to only parse the first element and not the whole list?

Comment: Perhaps this would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323887/partial-gson-deserialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a custom [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html):

```
private class MyCustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyModel> {

  @Override
  public MyCustomDeserializer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    // initialize an instance of your model
    MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) json; // get json array
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jArray.get(0); // get first object

    // do what you want with the first object
    myModel.setParameter(jsonObject.get("parameter").getAsInt());

    // ignore next json objects
    return myModel;
  } 
}
```

Then, initialize your `Gson` instance like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new MyCustomDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
MyModel model = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyModel.class);
```

If you want to exclude some fields from Serialization you need to declare them in your model as `transient`:

```
private transient String name; // will be ignored from Gson
```