# Class Loading vs Initialisation: Java static final variable

Tags: java, memory, jvm, classloading, in-class-initialization

Example.java

```
public class Example {

    static final int i = 10;
    static int j = 20;
    static {
        System.out.println("Example class loaded and initialized");
    }
}
```

Use.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Use {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch = 1;
        while(ch != 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            ch = sc.nextInt();

            if (ch == 1) {
                System.out.println("Example's i = " + Example.i);
            } else if(ch == 2){
                System.out.println("Example's j = " + Example.j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run with `java -verbose:class Use`, and give input as `1` then output is `10` i.e the constant `i` value. But `Example` class is not loaded yet.
However, when I give input as `2`, **only then** `Example` **class is loaded into the JVM, as visible by the verbose output**, and then static block inside Example is executed and also `j`'s value initialized and then printed.

**My Query is:** If for the input `1` i.e when the static final (constant) value of a class `Example` is requested in another class `Use`, then from where is that constant value fetched if the class `Example` was never loaded into the JVM till then?
When and how was the static final `i` intialized and store into the JVM memory?

Comment: Java may inline final static variables across classes at compilation(javac) time. This is to reduce the number of class loads.  I could of sworn I saw a very similar question a few days ago. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Old question but has info about this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524150/is-it-possible-to-disable-javacs-inlining-of-static-final-variables

Comment: @PiRocks that makes sense. Thanks for answering that and digging up the old question and providing a reference to that :)
so, is my understanding correct: that in the compiled Use.class file 'System.out.println("Example's i = " + Example.i)' is actually 'System.out.println("Example's i = " + 10)' in bytecode form?

Comment: Correct. You could check this for youself with `javap -v -p path/to/Use.class`

Comment: Awesome! I checked it now. It indeed is that. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Related: [Java static final values replaced in code when compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173372/java-static-final-values-replaced-in-code-when-compiling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Java language specification section 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) (emphasis added):

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before
> the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used **and the field is not a constant variable** (§4.12.4).

A [constant variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) is a final variable that is initialized with a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29). In your code, `Example.i` is a constant variable, and therefore does not cause the class to be loaded.

So if the class is not loaded, where does the value com from?

The language specification requires the compiler to inline its value. From section of [binary compatibility 13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1):

> 3. A reference to a field that is a constant variable (§4.12.4) must be
>    resolved at compile time to the value V denoted by the constant
>    variable's initializer.
>
>    If such a field is static, then no reference to the field should be
>    present in the code in a binary file, including the class or interface
>    which declared the field. Such a field must always appear to have been
>    initialized (§12.4.2); the default initial value for the field (if
>    different than V) must never be observed.